# How to close windows on screen keyboard with c++

Tags: c++, windows, on-screen-keyboard

I'm trying to close windows on-screen keyboard (osk.exe) in c++ code, but without any success.

```
HWND kbIsOpen = FindWindow(TEXT("OSKMainClass"),NULL);
CloseWindow(kbIsOpen);
```

`CloseWindow` or `SendMessage` didn't to anything.
Note that the problem is not in `kbIsOpen`, and also `getLastError` returns `5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)`.

What I can do to deal with this problem?

Comment: You might aswell kill the process, which would be more appropriate I guess.

Comment: *CloseWindow function: Minimizes (but does not destroy) the specified window.*

Comment: Windows API call would only send close window event to the application but the application can reject this

Comment: Also, see that with User Access Control activated you may need to elevate your application's privilege to do that.

Comment: If you can get by with hiding the window instead of completely killing the application give `ShowWindow` a try.

Comment: So, is there any way of closing Osk.exe without elevation? I haven't found any.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `FindWindow` returns a valid window handle, `SendMessage(kbIsOpen, WM_DESTROY, NULL, NULL);` should close it.  (Although it's kind of a dangerous way to do it.  Try sending `WM_CLOSE` and `WM_QUIT` first.)

However, it's possible that the keyboard window throws away destroy messages, and just keeps on going no matter what you throw at it.  I'm running Windows 7, so I can't tell you myself.

< unimportant opinion > `bkIsOpen` sounds like the name of a boolean variable telling you if the window is open, not a handle to the window if it exists. < /unimportant opinion >